# How to run the bash script in parallel rather than sequentially?

Tags: linux, bash, gnu-parallel

```
#!/bin/bash

some_array=($1)

echo "-- Setting-Up VM --"

for i in ${some_array[@]}; do
    echo "VM #: $i"

    case "$i" in

        "1")
        echo "Setting-Up VM $i"
        sshpass -p "root12"  ssh -tt -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@10.xx.x.xx <<EOF
        pwd
        nohup yes | /etc/rc.d/init.d/lifconfig
        su tarts
        nohup yes | vncserver
        sleep 10
        exit
        exit
EOF
        ;;

        "2")
        echo "Setting-Up VM $i"
        sshpass -p "root12"  ssh -tt -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@10.xx.x.xx <<EOF
        pwd
        nohup yes | /etc/rc.d/init.d/lifconfig
        su tarts
        nohup yes | vncserver
        sleep 10
        exit
        exit
EOF
        ;;

        "3")
        echo "Setting-Up VM $i"
        sshpass -p "root12"  ssh -tt -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@10.xx.x.xx <<EOF
        pwd
        nohup yes | /etc/rc.d/init.d/lifconfig
        su tarts
        nohup yes | vncserver
        sleep 10
        exit
        exit
EOF
        ;;
        *)
        echo "unknown VM!"
        ;;
    esac
done
```

Can someone please guide me I have the above script which is executed when we run the script for instance `./vmSetup.sh "1 2 3"` but this is executed sequentially. I had created this script but now I want to run the cases in the script i.e. 1, 2 and 3 in parallel. Can someone also tell me how to run for instance 8 cases in parallel?

Comment: Note about heredocs: `EOF` must be the **only** characters on the line ending the heredoc: no leading spaces are allowed. You can use leading *tabs* if you do `<<-EOF`

Comment: @glennjackman That was my mistake when fixing the rest of the indentation. It was correct before my edit

Comment: Why do you have the `case` statement in the first place? All the cases do the same things.

Comment: How can I use just one case statement and then use any of the 25 cases I have given in the script? The difference between the cases is only the IP addresses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put each `case ... esac` statement in the background by ending it with `&`. Then use `wait` after the loop to wait for all the background processes to finish.

```
#!/bin/bash

some_array=($1)

echo "-- Setting-Up VM --"

for i in ${some_array[@]}; do
    echo "VM #: $i"

    case "$i" in

        "1")
        echo "Setting-Up VM $i"
        sshpass -p "root12"  ssh -tt -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@10.xx.x.xx <<EOF
        pwd
        nohup yes | /etc/rc.d/init.d/lifconfig
        su tarts
        nohup yes | vncserver
        sleep 10
        exit
        exit
EOF
        ;;

        "2")
        echo "Setting-Up VM $i"
        sshpass -p "root12"  ssh -tt -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@10.xx.x.xx <<EOF
        pwd
        nohup yes | /etc/rc.d/init.d/lifconfig
        su tarts
        nohup yes | vncserver
        sleep 10
        exit
        exit
EOF
        ;;

        "3")
        echo "Setting-Up VM $i"
        sshpass -p "root12"  ssh -tt -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@10.xx.x.xx <<EOF
        pwd
        nohup yes | /etc/rc.d/init.d/lifconfig
        su tarts
        nohup yes | vncserver
        sleep 10
        exit
        exit
EOF
        ;;
        *)
        echo "unknown VM!"
        ;;
    esac &
done

wait
```

Comment: Thanks Barmar but also is there a way to do it with GNU Parallel?

Comment: Probably. But since I'm not familiar with GNU parallel I didn't use it in my answer.

Comment: Why don't you just run the whole script using GNU Parallel?

Comment: How can I do that with GNU Parallel? I don't know how to use the package even though I have installed it on my VM? Secondly, can you tell me how to run 8 cases in parallel at the same time?

Comment: Like I said, I'm not familiar with GNU Parallel. [unix.se] would be a better place to ask how to use that.

Comment: the one issue that I think might happen with sending it to background is that you will not know if the command actually passed/failed unless you put something to explicitly validate it

Comment: @abhishekphukan There's no error checking in the original synchronous version, either. It will just go on to the next case.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have a case statement at all when all these are identical?

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "-- Setting-Up VM(s) --"
for i in "$@"; do
case "$i" in
1) IP=1.2.3.4;;
2) IP=2.2.3.4;;
3) IP=3.2.3.4;;
*) echo "Invalid option '$i'" >&2; exit 1;;
esac
echo "Setting-Up VM $i"
sshpass -p root12 ssh -tt -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@$IP <<EOF &
  pwd
  nohup yes | /etc/rc.d/init.d/lifconfig
  su tarts
     nohup yes | vncserver
     sleep 10
     exit
  exit
EOF
done
```

To run a job in background, just use `&`

```
sshpass -p "root12"  ssh -tt -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@$IP <<EOF &
```

It's just confusing because of the here-doc, but the `&` metacharacter still parses correctly on my system. Try it.

Also, rather than quoting all your options in one string and then parsing them back out to an array, why not just simplify the whole thing and let them come in as separate arguments? Call it as

```
./vmSetup.sh 1 2 3 # NOT "1 2 3" with quotes
```

and the loop becomes just

```
for i in "$@" # properly quoted, though wouldn't matter for 1 2 3
```

This whole thing seems a lot simpler and easier to maintain.

Another option, which is what I would do: create a file that is a list of the DNS/IP addresses you need, then pass that file as the lone argument.

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r addr || [[ -n "$addr" ]]
do echo "Setting-Up VM $addr"
sshpass -p "root12"  ssh -tt -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@$addr <<EOF &
  pwd
  nohup yes | /etc/rc.d/init.d/lifconfig
  su tarts
     nohup yes | vncserver
     sleep 10
     exit
  exit
EOF
done < "$1"
```

Better, add valid error checking first to make sure the file exists and is readable, etc, but as a simple case, this should work.

For even better, cleaner, safer code, read https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 and follow those suggestions. :)

Comment: Yes can you please tell me how to use just one case statement and shorten the script. The IP is the difference only.

Answer (score 0):

If `./vmSetup.sh 1` works as expected, these should work:

```
parallel -j8 ./vmSetup.sh {} ::: 1 2 3 ... 100
seq 100 | parallel -j8 ./vmSetup.sh
```